# Bar chart label alignment

Tags: chart.js

My labels are aligning to the left side of my bars. I'm wanting them centered but I can't figure out how to make it happen. I checked the docs but I couldn't find the answer. Anyone know how to center them?

[image: Example]

Comment: check your offset is `true` or `false` and share your code we can't anything thing without code share your code here so we can clearify your problem in code

Comment: It looks like you have two datasets (where one is all null/0) and that's causing the alignment issue. But since you've not provided code it's impossible to debug. Therefore I'm voting to close.

Comment: @timclutton is correct. The chart is being initialized in a code template with an empty dataset and instead of using it, I add another to the list.

The code is distributed across several components even though I'm feeding it test data.